# git rebase process and alternatives

Tags: git, rebase

There is a github project, which I will refer to as A, that I add on very specific custom features to. And as A progresses with security patches and upgrades by its author, I `rebase` my custom features onto their latest code.

My custom features also come in layers, the lower layers are more generic while the higher layers, which rely on the lower layers, go on to become very specific.

So the end result is that some of my projects will use A + layer 1, and others will use A + layer 1 + layer 2 etc.

My question is, is `rebase` the correct approach to do what I'm trying to achieve? Or is there a more elegant way without having to juggle the whole source tree in my head as I'm doing the `rebase`. Thank you.

Comment: `git cherry-pick` is an alternative. But you still need to know well about the commit graph.

Answer (score 0):

Well, saying that rebase is **the** correct approach would be an overkill. But it's **a** correct approach, sure.

Another alternative would be merge. You have branch(es) in which you merge the branch from project A. Every time you update the branch from project A you merge the updated branch to your branch(es).

Comment: If you could go with rebase without getting too much or too difficult merges, I think that rebase is a better way to go than a merge...